# Having trouble painting custom buttons with swing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I wrote a short program because I wanted to create a custom-made button with rounded corners. Therefore I extended the JButton class and overwrote the paintComponent method (see code below).

```
public class JRoundedButton extends JButton {

private int arcRadius;

public JRoundedButton(String label, int arcRadius) {
    super(label);
    this.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    this.arcRadius = arcRadius;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if(g instanceof Graphics2D) {
        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        //Draw button background
        graphics.setColor(getBackground());
        graphics.fillRoundRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, arcRadius, arcRadius);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
    return new RoundRectangle2D.Double(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight(), arcRadius, arcRadius).contains(x,y);
}

public int getArcRadius() {
    return arcRadius;
}

public void setArcRadius(int arcRadius) {
    this.arcRadius = arcRadius;
    this.repaint();
}
```

}

When I create a simple frame and add ONE button to a panel, that I then add to the frame it shows up perfectly. But as soon as I want to create two buttons and set them below each other (having Borderlayout I used NORTH and SOUTH) only the upper button shows up correct. The button below displays the text correctly (I removed that part from the painComponent(...) method), but the background isn't painted. I do not use the setOpaque(...) method in any way.

What could the problem be?

Do I need to set the bounds of my custom button?

Edit:
Here is the code that creates the frame and displays the buttons:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Buttontest");
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    contentPanel.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    contentPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 0, 20));

    JRoundedButton button1 = new JRoundedButton("Rounded Button", 40);
    button1.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    button1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    JRoundedButton button2 = new JRoundedButton("Rounded Button 2", 40);
    button2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    button2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    contentPanel.add(button1);
    contentPanel.add(button2);

    frame.add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

The output is this:

[image: frame showing only one button corrent]

Why is the background of the lower button not visible? It should be black!

Comment: I think the button itself is good as far as the first button is working. In my opinion, the main code where you place the buttons may have a problem with the layout. So, it's better to provide us with that code and an image for the result.

Comment: Well then, where is the mistake? I added a screenshot, the lower background of the button must be black.

Comment: anyone an idea?

Comment: Try to put this in your button constructor: `this.setOpaque(false);`. I'm not sure if this is the problem or it's the layout of the frame using `frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `paintComponent()` you need `fillRoundRect(0,0,...)` instead of `getX()` and `getY()`
because g is relative to the component itself.

Comment: Yes!!!! That worked! Thanks so much, didn't think about that.